# Installed PC RAM of higher frequency but doesn't post

Tags: memory, upgrade, workstation

I bought used HyperX 1600 mhz 2*4gb sticks. Neither a buzzer from motherboard nor does it post. No option to change to 1600mhz in BIOS.
CPU- i3 2120
[ASUS Motherboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdXjz.jpg)
Any help plzz thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided said the max is 1333MHz for that motherboard.  1600MHz is *not* supported.  You will need to purchase memory that is supported by your motherboard.  If you already have memory installed on the motherboard and are adding *additional* memory, it is best to match the speed of the existing memory.

Comment: I heard some saying higher frequency will be detected by a motherboard but must maintain proper data rate, I think it's a inbuilt problem. But thanx!!

Comment: @VandanMS A motherboard can *only* run RAM at supported frequencies.  That RAM is too fast.